# Why my indentation can not work in python while True: loop

Tags: python, error-handling

hello in my code is a lot of error that we can remove only with restarting a script so I use a while true loop and try: to continue but I am still in the inclosed cycle. But please a code in if and else is not important only a indentation

```
while True:
    try: 
        # video tas can be used for an image 
        if len(video_tags) == 1:
            #That meaan that a code1 or code2 function will be activated 
            # I deleted a code1 function because a gifs was in the bad quality 
            code2_function()
            print("Function code2 has been activated")
            check_px("code_img.png")
            image_resize("code_img.png",1920,1080,"res_image.png")
            if get_rgb("res_image.png",1730,11) > 700:
                print("white")
                img_edit("res_image.png","QR_white.png",1580,20,"prep_image.png")
            else:
                print("black")
                img_edit("res_image.png","QR_black.png",1580,20,"prep_image.png")
            audiovizualizere("output.mp3","prep_image.png")
            #Everithink is done
            
        else:
            print(video_tag)
            video_or_image = random.choice(["image","video"])
            print(f"This a random picker to video_or_image:  {video_or_image}")
            if video_or_image == "image":
                pexels_or_pixabay_image = random.choice(["pexels","pixabay"])
                print(pexels_or_pixabay_image)
                if pexels_or_pixabay_image == "pexels":
                    print("A image to video from pexels has been activated!")
                    image_to_video_from_pexels(video_tag,"image_from_pexels.png")
                    check_px("img_from_pexels")
                    image_resize("img_from_pexels.png",1920,1080,"res_image.png")
                    if get_rgb("res_image.png",1730,11) > 700:
                        print("white")
                        img_edit("res_image.png","QR_white.png",1580,20,"prep_image.png")
                    else:
                        print("black")
                        img_edit("res_image.png","QR_black.png",1580,20,"prep_image.png")
                else:
                    # this is only temporary
                    print("A image to video from pexels has been activated!")
                    image_to_video_from_pexels(video_tag,"image_from_pexels.png")
                    check_px("img_from_pexels")
                    image_resize("img_from_pexels.png",1920,1080,"res_image.png")
                    if get_rgb("res_image.png",1730,11) > 700:
                        print("white")
                        img_edit("res_image.png","QR_white.png",1580,20,"prep_image.png")
                    else:
                        print("black")
                        img_edit("res_image.png","QR_black.png",1580,20,"prep_image.png)
                audiovizualizere("output.mp3","prep_image.png")    
        # Video section good
            else:
                # code here is not important 

               
        break
    except Exception:
        continue
```

where I have a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing `")` at the end of line 49, the line that says `img_edit("res_image.png","QR_black.png",1580,20,"prep_image.png`